# AngularJS promise blocking before controller runs

Tags: angularjs

A have an Angular JS application with the following:

A run block with the following to set the current user:

**javascript**

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $http){
  $http.get("/users/current").success(function(data){
    $rootScope.current_user = data;
  });
});
```

I set the /users/current route to take 5 seconds to resolve, to simulate poor network conditions.

My application uses ngRouter.  There is an "outer" controller, called Main Controller, and inside of it, there is ng-view:

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app>
  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <div ng-view>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The inner controller's code doesn't execute until AFTER the promise in the run block has resolved, so this works:

**javascript**

```
app.controller('InnerController', function($scope, $rootScope){
  $scope.logged_in_user = $rootScope.current_user.username;
  // logged in user is correct
  // alert($rootScope.current_user.username); // This will work 
});
```

The main controller's code execute BEFORE the promise in the run block has resolved, so this doesn't work:

**javascript**

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $rootScope){
  $scope.logged_in_user = $rootScope.current_user.username;
  // logged in user is undefined
  // alert($rootScope.current_user.username); // This will throw an exception, as current_user is undefined, and you are trying to call the property username on undefined.
});
```

Questions

1. Why is the behavior different between these two controllers?
2. Is there a way to guarantee that the behavior is the same?  That Angular waits until the promise is resolved in the run block before it runs the controller?
3. If not, is there a way I can place the promise onto the $rootScope, and just get the value that the promise returns?  I need to be able to do this in multiple places, and I don't want to $watch any variables.

Comment: Are you sure the inner controller's code isn't executing before and then simply refreshing once `$rootScope.current_user` is redefined by the promise?

Comment: Thanks for looking at my issue.  Yes, I'm sure.  I put an alert inside of the inner controller and main controller that look like this: alert("MainController:"+$rootScope.current_user) and alert("InnerController:"+$rootScope.current_user).  The alert in the main controller has an undefined current_user, and the alert for the indicators controller fires 5 seconds later, and the current_user is defined there.

Comment: Change it to a `console.log` instead.  The alert may be blocking your code and giving the API time to return before InnerController is instantiated.

Comment: Can you include the markup that contains `InnerController`?

Comment: tyler - That's what I thought at first, but it's not the case.  The HTTP GET request for /users/current isn't sent to the server until AFTER you hit OK at the alert for MainController, so it doesn't matter how long you wait before hitting OK.
Ed - Do you mean the template for InnerController?  No matter what it contains, the behavior is the same.  It can be blank for this example.